# Indy, IdTCPSever sending data in utf=8 charset

Tags: delphi, utf-8, indy10, tcpserver

I have problem with conversion strings to utf-8. 
I use standard Indy method for sending with conversion inside:

```
 AContext.Connection.IOHandler.writeln(Utf8Encode('ĄĘÓ'));
```

but the client reads them like '???' - 3f 3f 3f in hex (I checked it by using WireShark too).

I use Delphi XE and Indy 10.

Big thanks for any help.

~Artik

Comment: I know I can use something like that: AContext.Connection.IOHandler.writeln('ĄĘÓ',TIdTextEncoding.UTF8); but what can I do to send TStringlist intead of ordinary string. Iteration by TStringlist elements doesn't bring solve in my situation.

Comment: There is a `TIdIOHandler.Write()` method overload for `TStrings` data, and it has an optional `TIdTextEncoding` parameter, eg: `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(MyStringList, False, TIdTextEncoding.UTF8);`

Answer (score 3):

I found solution for my problem, I think the simplest by using code like below:

```
uses
  IdGlobal;

begin
  aContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
end;
```